# TwitterAPI filter location using Premium options

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to extract tweets around a certain location using the 30day or full archive data from Twitter. For that I'm using the TwitterAPI library, but I keep on getting an error when constraining to location.

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI

api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token_key, access_token_secret)

PRODUCT = '30day'
LABEL = 'development'
SEARCH_TERM = 'JFK'


r = api.request('tweets/search/%s/:%s' % (PRODUCT, LABEL),
                {'query':SEARCH_TERM, 'point_radius':'[-73.7781 40.6413 2km]'})

for item in r:
    print(item['text'] if 'text' in item else item)
```

I always get the same error but I can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /Users/Fil/PycharmProjects/Twitter/importtweets.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Fil/PycharmProjects/Twitter/importtweets.py", line 18, in <module>
    for item in r:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TwitterAPI/TwitterAPI.py", line 219, in __iter__
    return self.get_iterator()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/TwitterAPI/TwitterAPI.py", line 206, in get_iterator
    raise TwitterRequestError(self.response.status_code)
TwitterAPI.TwitterError.TwitterRequestError: Twitter request failed (422)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`point_radius` must go inside the `query` value. Try:

```
SEARCH_TERM = 'JFK point_radius:[-73.7781 40.6413 2km]'
```